# VHDL - how to detect and output correct priority

Tags: vhdl, encoder

Currently, I am working on a parking lot system in VHDL.

The goal is simple. When a car parks, it will take a look at all the available spots and output the next empty spot. Seem simple enough, but I am having some problems getting it to work properly.

I am using switches on a board and detecting when the switches are up. That signifies weather there is a car parked there or not.

The goal is that I can hit for example, switch 1, switch 2 and switch 4 and till output 3 as the available spot. Then, if I switch on 3, it'll recalculate and say 5 is the next available spot.

To accomplish this, I am using a bunch of if else statements, but whats happening is that the for example, if I hit the #4 switch, it'll properly display 5, but then once i hit the #5 switch, it will continue to show 5 as the next available spot rather than 6.

I think my problem is that I don't have enough conditions to cover all scenarios. Is there a way for me to write this in a shorter way?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity Priority is
port(
    SWITCH: in std_logic_vector (8 downto 0);
    H1: out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    H2: out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    H3: out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    H4: out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0)
);
end Priority;

architecture Behavioral of Priority is

begin 
process (SWITCH)
begin

if (SWITCH(0) = '1' AND SWITCH(1) = '1' AND SWITCH(2) = '1' AND SWITCH(3) = '1' AND SWITCH(4) = '1' AND SWITCH(5) = '1' AND SWITCH(6) = '1' AND SWITCH(7) = '1')   then  --if all switches are on, display "FULL"


H1 <= "1100";
H2 <= "1100";
H3 <= "1011";
H4 <= "1010";


elsif SWITCH(0) = '1' then  --if switch 0 is turned on, show "PS-1"

H1 <= "1101";
H2 <= "1110";
H3 <= "1111";
H4 <= "0010";



elsif SWITCH(1) = '1' then  --if switch 1 is turned on, show "PS-2"

H1 <= "1101";
H2 <= "1110";
H3 <= "1111";
H4 <= "0011";



elsif SWITCH(2) = '1' then  

H1 <= "1101";
H2 <= "1110";
H3 <= "1111";
H4 <= "0100";



elsif SWITCH(3) = '1' then  

H1 <= "1101";
H2 <= "1110";
H3 <= "1111";
H4 <= "0101";



elsif SWITCH(4) = '1' then  

H1 <= "1101";
H2 <= "1110";
H3 <= "1111";
H4 <= "0110";



elsif SWITCH(5) = '1' then  

H1 <= "1101";
H2 <= "1110";
H3 <= "1111";
H4 <= "0111";


elsif SWITCH(6) = '1' then  

H1 <= "1101";
H2 <= "1110";
H3 <= "1111";
H4 <= "1000";



elsif SWITCH(7) = '1' then  

H1 <= "1101";
H2 <= "1110";
H3 <= "1111";
H4 <= "0001";


end if;
--end if;

end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: There's no arithmetic in your code, so why include non-standardized packages `STD_LOGIC_ARITH` and `STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED`? You should remove them. And if you decide to add arithmetic, please use the standardized package `numeric_std`.

Comment: I have other vhdl code that are using these packages so just to be safe, I included them. Do I not need to do that? Are each vhdl file seperate even if I am connecting them with a top file?

Comment: How does your reading audience interpret *...show 5 as the next available spot rather than 6* with respect to your code? What do H1 - H4 mean?  Have you simulated?

Comment: H1 - H4 are four Seven Segment Display on my board. What I am doing is that for example, if the #one spot , the board will display

PS-1

if its full, the board will display

FULL

in the seven segment display on the board.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a loop to iterate through the SWITCH input and detect the first empty spot. That makes your code also more generic, i.e. it's easier to support hundreds of parking spots with a loop construct rather than if-else statements.

```
process(switch)
    variable v_empty_slot : integer;
begin
    v_empty_slot := -1; --default value

    for i in SWITCH'low to SWITCH'high loop
        if SWITCH(i)='0' then
            v_empty_slot := i;
            exit;
        end if;
    end loop;

    --add code here to map v_empty_slot to H1,H2,H3,H4

end process;
```

Note: I have not verified that code snippet.

Comment: Map the v_empty_slot? I am sorry, but I am new to the world of VHDL. My output that is changing is going to be H4, so how would I go about doing that? I can do the rest manually if I have that one example (if you don't mind)

Comment: @TheRealPdGaming You have to add code that converts the integer value in v_empty_slot to a std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) as you need it for H4. From your example, I cannot understand the encoding of your values for H4, so finding an appropriate conversion/mapping is up to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so if there is anyone who has the same problem as me in the future, this is how I solved it.

I said I had a parking lot with 8 spots and needed to know when a spot was avaiable. What I was doing wrong was that I was detecting when a car came and trying to find the next avaibale spot. Bad Idea. What happenes is that there is so many possibilities for combinations (8 X 8 so total of 64 combinations) per parking spots that unless you write them out, its totally not worth it.

The better way to go about doing this is detecting when there ISN't a car. That way, the highest priority will always be active so that regarless of where they park, as long as they don't park in the priority spot, it'll continue to be the priority. If they do park at the priority spot, then it'll look for the next spot without a car rather than a spot where there is a car and trying to find the right prioty. Am I making any sense here? I hope I am.

Here is what I mean in code form.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

ENTITY Priority IS     PORT
(  switch:     IN    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 DOWNTO 0);
   H1:     out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
   H2:     out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
   H3:     out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
   H4:     out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0)
    );
END Priority;

ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF Priority IS
BEGIN
--SIGNAL Sel : STD_LOGIC;    
Process(switch)

BEGIN


    if switch(7 downto 0) = "11111111" then

     H4<= "1010";
     H3<= "1011";    
     H2<= "1100";    
     H1<= "1100";    

    elsif switch(0) = '0' then
     H4<= "0001";
     H3<= "1111";    
     H2<= "1110";    
     H1<= "1101";

    elsif switch(1) = '0' then
     H4<= "0010" ;
     H3<= "1111";    
     H2<= "1110";    
     H1<= "1101";

    elsif switch(2) = '0' then
     H4<= "0011" ;
     H3<= "1111";    
     H2<= "1110";    
     H1<= "1101";

    elsif switch(3) = '0' then
     H4<= "0100" ;
     H3<= "1111";    
     H2<= "1110";    
     H1<= "1101";

    elsif switch(4) = '0' then
     H4<= "0101";
     H3<= "1111";    
     H2<= "1110";    
     H1<= "1101";

    elsif switch(5) = '0' then
     H4<= "0110";
     H3<= "1111";    
     H2<= "1110";    
     H1<= "1101";

    elsif switch(6) = '0' then
     H4<= "0111";
     H3<= "1111";    
     H2<= "1110";    
     H1<= "1101";

    elsif switch(7) = '0' then
     H4<= "1000";
     H3<= "1111";    
         H2<= "1110";    
     H1<= "1101";

    else
     H4<= "0000";     
     H3<= "1111";    
     H2<= "1110";    
     H1<= "1101";
    end if;

    end process;

END Behavioral;
```

If the binary doesn't make sense to you, don't worry. Just take a look at the binary for h4. When all switches are 1, then it displays FULL. If switch 1 is down, it'll display 1. So, as long as switch 1 is down, it'll continue to display 1 regardless. if it goes up, it moves on to the next one and checks to see if its available. Thats it.